# Post variables from a second table in form

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm trying post 3 variables in order to insert them in table2.  As you can see I'm using a SELECT to get 3 variables from table1 to insert into a table2 but can't see the input value when looking at the source.

The loop works. I get results in the loop but the input post echo's nothing.  I've tried many different ways but can't seem to get it to work. Can someone help?

```
<?php
include('theconnection.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbName);
if (!$con)
 {
 die('cannot connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
 mysqli_select_db($con,"thebooks");
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM books");
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT b.id, b.name, b.cover, b.pageno FROM books");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo ("<input type='text' value='$row[name]' name='name' id='name'>");
echo ("<input type='text' value='$row[cover]' name='cover' id='cover'>");
echo ("<input type='text' value='$row[pageno]' name='pageno' id='pageno'>");
 }
?>                   

<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo "{$_POST['name']}"; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cover" id="cover" value="<?php echo "{$_POST['cover']}"; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="pageno" id="pageno" value="<?php echo "{$_POST['pageno']}"; ?>">
```

Comment: Can we see the complete `form`?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM books` => `");` is missing at the end of the line. (BTW I don't know why you execute this query as you overrides `$result` the line below - and you don't seem to try using it anywhere)

Comment: ?? what are you talking about?   $result is in the while loop.  Please focus on the issue which is in the hidden input, It's not echoing the variables.  The loop is working fine.

Comment: sorry but i don't know what did you do its not enough! do you use form tag ? where is your submit button

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM books");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT b.id, b.name, b.cover, b.pageno FROM books");
```

I don't see why there are two queries. You can just drop the first one. Also, I'd like to suggest you this-

Instead of echoing like this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo ("<input type='text' value='$row[name]' name='name' id='name'>");
echo ("<input type='text' value='$row[cover]' name='cover' id='cover'>");
echo ("<input type='text' value='$row[pageno]' name='pageno' id='pageno'>");
 }
```

echo it like this-

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<input type='text' value='" . $row[name] . "' name='name' id='name'>";
echo "<input type='text' value='" . $row[cover] . "' name='cover' id='cover'>";
echo "<input type='text' value='" . $row[pageno] . "' name='pageno' id='pageno'>";
}
```

In your last bit of code, please make these small changes-

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cover" id="cover" value="<?php echo $_POST['cover']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="pageno" id="pageno" value="<?php echo $_POST['pageno']; ?>">
```

Please clarify- why would you echo input controls in a loop? You could potentially get hundreds of input controls rendered on your page. Now you don't want that do you? Hope my answer helps.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  I was testing in the loop to see if I was grabbing the name, cover, and pageno variables.  The hidden inputs are to grab the variables and post them.   But the problem still exist even with your code. The name, cover, and pageno columns in the db are empty.  The only variable that's inserted is the id.   I'm also trying to populate the name, cover, and pageno in an email.   I wish what you posted worked.  It must be hard to do with a combo box.